How can I get the path of a folder selected by the user through a file input, without requiring them to upload the files inside the folder?
How can I get the path of a folder selected by the user through a file input, without requiring them to upload the files inside the folder?
My intention is for the user to provide me with the path where he wants to save the file that I will provide to him
When they select the folder, I want it to display only the path. I am using Angular 17.
I tried using the webkitdirectory attribute, but it accesses all the files within the folder, which is not what I want to do.

Please provide a code sample of what have you tried so far. A screenshot also could be helpful. Thanks

As far as I can tell, you can't. And with good reason. This is a security protocol, as it can be quite dangerous for a web application to get a hold of a user's personal file path directory. Here are some links you can look at to read up more on what you can use with the  element and not.
HTML spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#fakepath-srsly
MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#value
You can however, show the user a relative path.
Look at this SO answer: html5/Javascript - How to get the Selected folder name?
